# have search bar handle one tap and two taps differently

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to flutter/dart, so this might be a silly question...

I wanted to have a search bar, that when tapped the first time, displays a series of listview tiles (like pre-canned search terms).  I wanted a subsequent tap to then open the soft keyboard for user input.  As it stands now, a single tap opens the listview tiles, and also opens the soft keyboard.

After some looking around, I am thinking I would need to wrap the searchbar in a GestureDetector, and handle the tap / double-tap gestures through that.   What I can't quite figure out, is how to tie the GestureDetector gestures, ontap and ondoubletap, to the child widget actions... I think when the searchbar gets focus (onTap), the soft keyboard opens, so not sure if that behavior can be (easily) uncoupled...

The flutter cookbook example uses this:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

but the API docs say this only manages snackbars and MaterialBanners:
"Manages SnackBars and MaterialBanners for descendant Scaffolds."

Here is the framework I have so far:

```
Widget searchBar() {
    //final FloatingSearchBarController searchBarController = FloatingSearchBarController();
    return
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: ()  =>{},
          onDoubleTap: () => {},
          child: FloatingSearchBar(
            controller: searchBarController,
            hint: "search",
            openAxisAlignment: 0.0,
            width: 600,
            axisAlignment: 0.0,
            scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 20),
            elevation: 4.0,
            onQueryChanged: (query) {

            },
            builder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> transition) {
              return ClipRRect(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Item 1'),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Item 2'),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: const Text('Item 3'),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              );
            },
          )
      );
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try the `SearchDelegate`

Comment: thank you @Davis I am going through documentation on this now.  Appreciate pointing me in the right direction.